# Parachute activates on launch problem

Tags: kerbal-space-program

So in Kerbal Space Program Im using the MK2 Radial Mounted Parachute, attached to the side of a Science Jr. Module. The issue im facing is that at launch the parachute automatically activates causing me to crash.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is likely that you have your parachutes set to activate on the first stage. The confusing thing here is that stage 0 is the **last** stage to be activated. Whereas the highest number will be activated first.

When setting your stages for your rocket, when you push space to activate the next stage, the stage at the bottom will activated first. In the example below this would be stage 8.

Ensure that your parachutes are on different stages to your rockets and that your parachutes are the last stage to activate, (the stage highest on the screen ie. stage zero).

[image: KSP Stages]